# Node.js: Check the root of the path.format()

Tags: node.js, path

See the following example for the `path.format()`:

```
require('path').format({ root: '/Users/joe', name: 'test', ext: 'txt' }) //  '/Users/joe/test.txt'
```

This example is written in [nodejs.dev](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-path-module#pathformat) and it is said that the output is as follows:

```
/Users/joe/test.txt
```

But I have tested this code on both Linux and Windows, but the result is as follows:

```
/Users/joetesttxt
```

What is the reason for this difference?
Is the example of this site wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example shown is for POSIX, where as Windows & Linux have different ways of doing it (because of the differences in file structure).

If we use the opposite function `parse`, and convert `C:\\Users\\joe\\test.txt` to the object we'd need to use in `format`, we get.

```js
path.parse('C:\\Users\\joe\\test.txt')
// returns
{
  root: 'C:\\',
  dir: 'C:\\Users\\joe',
  base: 'test.txt',
  ext: '.txt',
  name: 'test'
}
```

So this gives an example as to what you'd need to give `format` for Windows.

If we do the same in Linux, we get.

```js
path.parse('/home/joe/test.txt')
{
  root: '/',
  dir: '/home/joe',
  base: 'test.txt',
  ext: '.txt',
  name: 'test'
}
```

We can however, omit `root` and `base` as they are represented in `dir` and `name+ext` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my question is, does not the Linux file system extend POSIX? So why is the output of the example above something else on Linux?

Comment: I believe that most Linux distributions are only partly POSIX compliant. For example, `bash` shifted away from POSIX at one point (though some features still work)